# How to draw parallel or curved labels for OSM data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, labeling, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to recreate a Google style map using OpenStreetMap data and QGIS. I've been following underdarks many wonderful guides but am getting stuck at the labels. The OSM data was taken from geofabrik and imported into a postgreSQL/postgis database using osm2pgsql. When I try to label the roads it seems to place them as points and does not give the option for parallel or curved labeling. You can see the result below.

[image]

When I click on the advanced tab for labeling all I see are the data defined placement options and no check box for curved or parallel labeling. I'm new to QGIS so I hope I'm missing something really simple.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. It had to do with the label tool I was using. The label dialog from the GIS layer properties doesn't have the advanced options I was looking for but when I chose the label dialog from the labeling toolbar I did find the curved options I needed.